# How find Exact match and ignore second number in the text string on Google Sheet?

Tags: string, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, string-matching

I have text in A2: A7. Using the REGEXMATCH function, I need to evaluate in column B2: B7 as TRUE only the text that contains
age 0
age 1
age 2
However, this formula evaluates as TRUE as well
age 10
age 11
age 12
How can this formula be defined? Thank you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2YaK.jpg)

Formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXMATCH(A2:A7,"age 2|age 0|age 1"))
```

Here is document: [enter link description here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/152SSBPcYZi7ZxkdcHmPSbStgsWfM37prUrYZ-Us1AE8/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXMATCH(A2:A7,"\b(age 2|age 0|age 1)\b"))
```

[image]

Comment: i would vote this as an answer :)

Comment: Great. Well thank you. What does the letter ..b .. mean in the formula "\ b age .... \ b"

Comment: @RobertGy \b stands for boundary - in other words, it checks where words start and ends

Comment: @player0 Thank so much for your answers,

Answer (score 0):

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXMATCH(A2:A7&" ","age 2[^0-9]|age 0[^0-9]|age 1[^0-9]"))
```

&" " is to make sure there is something not numberish to match after the age

Comment: Great. Well thank you.